# How to define functions in iex main scope?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

In file `~/.iex.exs` I have a module defined with several functions and I want to call those functions from `iex` shell without the module name prefix.

Using `import SomeModule` does not work, I'm getting error:
`module SomeModule is not loaded but was defined. This happens because you are trying to use a module in the same context it is defined. Try defining the module outside the context that requires it.`

Is there some way of doing this in the `~/.iex.exs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the `.iex.exs` mechanism. The `.iex.exs` file is evaluated in the same context as the one you type stuff in in the shell: basically, IEx loads the `.iex.exs` just as if you typed it in the shell.

In Elixir, you can't define a module and import it in the same context (e.g., you can't define a module in the shell/in a file and import it thereafter) and that is what is happening there.

My advice is: define the module in `.iex.exs` and alias it (still in `.iex.exs`) to a very short name. For example, in `.iex.exs`:

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def foo, do: :foo
end

alias MyModule, as: M
```

Then, in the shell:

```
iex> M.foo
:foo
```

It's not optimal but right now, it's a possible compromise.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing actually. I hope one day Elixir will get the ability to define functions outside of modules in iex.

Answer (score 0):

`import SomeModule` is supported in recent versions.

`.iex.exs`:

```
defmodule IexHelpers do
   def foo, do: :foo
end

import IexHelpers
```